# Was there an idiomatic usage of "horse market" in 1940s New York?

Tags: idioms

There's an old article from the New Yorker, called ["Eleven Blue Men" (Berton Roueche, 1947)](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1948/06/05/the-case-of-the-eleven-blue-men), about an outbreak of cyanosis in Manhattan, which public health officials traced back to a mislabeled can of saltpetre at a dingy cafeteria called the Eclipse. One of the officials, describing the Eclipse, says,

> [It was] strictly a horse market, and dirtier than most.

Does "horse market" have a specific meaning in this context?  Is it just a poetic way of saying the place was dirty?  Is he suggesting they served horse meat?  Or maybe that junkies liked to hang out there (since "horse" can sometimes mean heroin)?

Comment: Possibly euphemistic for low-class pick-up joint, like "cattle market" or "meat market"?

Comment: That said, I think serving horse meat is the most likely. I can't find any references for any particular meaning though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an interesting reference [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=K3zPLTfP5EAC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=slang%20phrase%20%22a%20horse%20market%22&source=bl&ots=1Jo8COqARF&sig=vQp--RlcSKTCQH16humJRzA1IE8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEuZiXprjUAhVILFAKHWT8CdIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=slang%20phrase%20%22a%20horse%20market%22&f=false) that leads me to conclude that, differently from cattle markets or other meat markets, horse markets were particularly known as hangouts of ne'er do wells and scammers — largely due to the prevalence of horse thievery and the subsequent need to sell stolen horses quickly. Reading your quote, I interpret the official to be saying that the place was overrun with undesireables and was filthy.

Comment: That's very suggestive.  I do wish I could find a citation for the actual usage, but your interpretation is plausible.